# Why cron job is not running on some specified time in cpanel reseller club

Tags: php, mysql, cron, cpanel

I have tried cron jobs to run a mysql query, which should be run on `11:59 pm` daily but its not working and when I set it to some common settings that run every one minute then it works.

This is what i have tried

```
59 23 * * * php -f /home/empow5xr/public_html/closing.php
```

When I set it to run every minute or every 5 minute such as

```
*/5 * * * * php -f /home/empow5xr/public_html/closing.php
```

Then it works, but not on some specified time.

I have also tried changing the server timezone by editing `.htaccess` file

```
SetEnv TZ Asia/Kolkata
```

But it still not working don't know why.
I have tried finding the answers google but didn't get any satisfied answer.
Any suggestions...

Comment: please post output of `cat /var/log/syslog | grep CRON `

Comment: I'm not creating a manual cronjob I'm using cpanel common settings so how should I do that and I also didn't recieve any email from that as its said every time the cron runs you will recieve an email

Comment: And what does this really have to do with MySql (or even PHP)?

Comment: Because I want to run mysql query inside php script thats why